# Last row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm sure this will be answered VERY quickly but its beginning to do my head in!

I have a stockcheck spreadsheet in Google Sheets. The stock check is done on a tablet and the data is sync'd with google sheets whereby the data from that stock check is appended in rows consecutively.

So week 1 would transfer to row 1, week 2 to row 2 etc etc etc.

The number of items on the stock check may decrease or increase to the length so consequently so the row length will do as well.

I want to transfer that raw data to a second sheet but only the last row, so I can in effect get the data from the most recent stock check.

I've tried numerous functions and can return both the number of the last row and the value of the first column in the last row.

I'm just at a complete loss in returning the values of the entire last row. Please help!

Comment: For illustration, please share what you have already tried, and maybe a screenshot of how your data looks. For example, your formula for returning the number of the last row. Perhaps INDEX() is the function you need to read about?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your inventory sheet, I had to make one that is extremely simple (only has 3 columns). Next time, it would be helpful if you shared a link to your sheet (or at least made a copy of your sheet with insensitive data that you could share with us). Baring that data, I had to assume that you want the LATEST inventory row, and that you have a column with the date of the inventory in it...

Here's the sheet I created:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_H73BKJJDYdJYmKz6C_qDCzQ5TaByo6PcED2nRFCDBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I created a filter in Cell A1 that gets all the columns in your range, and then returns that data filtered by all dates that are in the past, orders the array by date, and then limits the rows returned by 1 (and the columns by the number of columns in your range):

```
=array_constrain(sort(filter($A$4:$C,$A$4:$A<=today()),1,false),1,columns(A:C))
```